# Android MVVM: How to merge two values in the use case

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, design-patterns, mvvm

I have this use case **GetPeopleUseCase** which allows me to retrieve data (students and footballers) from cache. Now, I have to merge footballer and student in one list. How can i do it?

```
class GetPeopleUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val footballerRepository: FootballerRepository,
    private val studentRepository: StudentRepository
) {
    suspend fun execute(): Result<List<Person>> {
        val footballer = footballerRepository.getFootballers()
        val student = studentRepository.getStudents()
        // How do I merge footballer and student?
    }
}
```

Person:

```
abstract class Person
```

Footballer:

```
data class Footballer(
    val name: String,
    val code: String
) : Person()
```

Student:

```
data class Student(
    val name: String,
    val code: String
): Person()
```

Comment: Do both contain a list of `Person`?

Comment: @Ivo Yes, correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do something like this:

```
if (footballer.isSuccess && student.isSuccess) {
    return Result.success(footballer.getOrThrow() + student.getOrThrow())
}
if (footballer.isSuccess) return footballer
return student
```

This way it combines them when both are success, or returns just one of them if they are success. And returns the student result if both were failed. If you want to return a failed result when either fail you could do

```
if (footballer.isSuccess && student.isSuccess) {
    return Result.success(footballer.getOrThrow() + student.getOrThrow())
}
if (footballer.isFailure) return footballer
return student
```

Comment: No, I can't, because it suggests: "Create extension function Result<List<Person>>.plus"

Comment: @JonathanQuaranta oh I assumed they were `List<Person>`, not `Result<List<Person>>`. in that case get the result from it maybe. Like `val persons = footballer.getOrThrow() + student.getOrThrow()` maybe. Though you probably should handle the cases when either results are not succesful

Comment: @JonathanQuaranta see my edit